# Wallet balance management after signing only once (logging into dapp)

Tags: anchor, phantom, transfer, signature

How to make a transfer from a user's wallet without confirming the signature of the transaction itself?

The user creates only a free signature when the dapp is first launched. A game is being developed in which all debit logic must occur without the user signing each transfer transaction.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. If you want to debit user's amount in your dApp, the user must sign a transaction. Signing transaction is mandatory step which you cannot skip for the user, otherwise, anyone would be able to send a user's funds without them knowing, which would be a major security issue.

However, you can ask user to debit x amount of tokens into your platform, and then your platform can directly utilize those deposited tokens to perform any kind of action.